# Job search: timing of interviews

Tags: hiring-process, applications

I’m searching for jobs (Europe) and I sent out 5 applications on the same day. One of the (smaller) companies replied to me by e-mail that night already (just before midnight) that they want to invite me for an interview. I’d like to work for them because they are young and growing, international, and I like the target group they’re working for. But I have a few concerns:

- I also applied to bigger companies where I can learn a lot more, but they didn’t respond yet (it has been only 2 days).
- I don’t meet all of the requirements for the first company and I’m not sure if the boss did read my CV that well. The invitation was quite quick and brief, and late at night. Didn’t they have other applicants or are they just inviting everyone? I also have questions about the job description itself, as it seemed less professional and a bit vague.

Now I think I want to go to the interview but I’d also like to wait a bit until the other companies invite or decline me. I don’t have so much work experience so I’d like to have some options to choose from, to see where I fit the best and where I can grow in my profession. I’m still searching for other interesting vacancies but haven’t found more yet.

**Main question: how do you manage the timing of going to interviews, so that you have more options open? I don’t want to reply slowly to the first company or keep companies waiting for a long time.**

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4):

I believe you are overthinking things. **Go to the interviews when they come up**, because:

- You give more information to the employer on your suitability ("I don’t meet all of the requirements for the first company and I’m not sure if the boss did read my CV that well")
- You gain information on which of the businesses you would prefer to work with, *if* an offer is extended to you ("I also applied to bigger companies where I can learn a lot more")
- Delaying attending interviews because you *may* be invited to others is not going to sit well with the hiring manager. They care about their problems and their timescales, not on the often slow processes of some other company ("but they didn’t respond yet")

Answer (score 4):

You were invited for the first interview for one company. That doesn't mean this company is going to make you an offer, and for sure it doesn't mean the other companies will be interested in interviewing you. Your focus should be on getting as many interviews as possible with different companies (as long as you are interested in those positions, of course). Some of these interviews will go great, and you might receive an offer. Some of them will not and you won't hear from them again.

Once you receive a job offer from a company, or two, or three, you will be able to decide what to do. You can accept one of them, ask for some time to think about it (if they give you that flexibility), negotiate, or reject the offer. But again, so far you have nothing, and there's no way you can know if these companies you've applied for are going to contact you or not.

Regarding your two concerns:

- You won't necessarily learn more in bigger companies. In my personal experience, it's completely the opposite, but it depends on the companies, the role, and you.
- Why are you making assumptions about the way they read your CV? They will have questions for you, the same way you (should) have questions for them. Remember an interview is a bidirectional conversation, in which both parties should find out more about the other one, to see if they would be a good fit. As long as you don't lie in your CV, it's fine. It's really hard to tick all the boxes in a job description, so don't worry.

Comment: Thank you, you're right that my focus should be getting as much interviews as I can. I'll go to the interview regardless the requirements and I'll see how it goes.

What happens normally when people have more offers? Can you request a time to think about an offer?

Comment: If you have multiple offers, that means you have more flexibility for negotiations. You can say that you need, let's say, 5 days to think about it if that would be ok for them, and you can also use another offer to get a better offer from this company. For example: "I'm genuinely interested in working with you, company X. However, company Y is offering me 5k more. If you are able to match their offer, I'll accept it right away". Of course, they might tell you "No, this is our final offer". Again, this is a two-way negotiation, and they might be also negotiating with more than one candidate.